# How to store curl response in a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I am working on an API. When I make request curl print the response on browser. So, my question is how to store response in variable? and How to insert it into database?

```
<?php
//API Url
$url = 'http://114.143.206.69:803/StandardForwardStagingService.svc/GetAWBNumberGeneratedSeries';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
      "BusinessUnit" => "ECOM",
      "ServiceType" => "FORWARD",
      "BatchID" => "Jopu7E9821"
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','XBKey:******'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

[My Response after var_dump($result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CfUr.png)

Comment: You will get response in $result variable. You can just do print_r($result); to check what coming in response and use that to store in db.

Comment: It's already storing data in `$result`. Also use json format to store whole response in database.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Yes you are right, we use Json Format for storing into database, It's working for me also. Amrendra Please look into this.

Comment: @JasminMistry when I use print_r($result), i get 1 and when I use var_dump($result), I get error Array to string conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation ...

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

So your code has to look like this

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// as you mentioned the response is a json string (screenshot)
$decoded_result = json_decode($result);

// output it on the screen
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";

// insert into database (in case $result is an array)
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (:result1, :result2)";

$pdo = new \PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    ':result1' => $result['bla'],
    ':result2' => $result['blubb'],
]);
```

That should be all you have to do.

Comment: var_dump($result); gives me bool(true)

Comment: Are you sure the endpoint returns any data? In case your endpoint returns any data: How should the response look like? Can you add the expected result to your post above? A return of the value 1 or true means, that the request was successful.

Comment: I added a screenshot. check it sir. After removing CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, I get bool(true)

Comment: So your return message is a json encoded string. Do not remove `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` Just decode it and use the contents. Example: `json_decode($result);`.